# Twitter typeahead bloodhound not prefetching

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, coffeescript, typeahead.js

I have this code to setup twitter typeahead and it's not working at all. I verified that the json is the correct format and has the right value etc. Any help would be much appreciated. Currently, it only logs the `'Initializing autocomplete'` line. The log in the filter is never called, which seems like the engine is not initializing for some reason. When I type, I see the empty template I defined. Also I did verify to make sure the coffeescript compiled to the proper format.

```
  initAutocomplete: ->
    console.log 'Initializing autocomplete'
    engine = new Bloodhound
      datumTokenizer: (d) ->
        Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace(d.val)
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
      limit: 10
      prefetch: 
        url:'../api/v3/tickets/autocomplete'
        filter: (list) ->
          console.log 'List: '
          console.log list
    engine.initialize()

    $('#tt-ticket.typeahead').typeahead null,
      name: 'tickets'
      displayKey: 'val'
      source: engine.ttAdapter()
      templates:
        empty: [
          '<div class="empty-message">',
          'Unable to find any matches',
          '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><strong>{{key}}</strong> – {{value}}</p>')
```

The json has been verified to have this format:

```
[{"key":"Id","val":1}, {"key":"Some other key", "val" : "some val"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my dumb mistake that the filter callback I was using to test if the list existed was returning undefined because that's the return value of `console.log`